# List is not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x

the last part of my program is not showing up, can someone help me?

Given a list of numbers, normalize the values in the list to be in the range [0,1]. First find the minimum and the maximum values in the list, min_val and max_val. Change every element, x, of the list to a new value, y, s.t. y = (x-min_val)/(max_val-min_val). Print the modified list. 
For example list: [2,1,3,4] becomes: [0.3333333333333333, 0.0, 0.6666666666666666, 1.0] 
You can hardcode a sample list in your program, but the solution should not depend on it. That is, if we only modify that list and rerun your program, it should produce the correct result based on the new list.

```
mylist=[3,1,5,9,2]
n=len(mylist)
newlist=[]
print("orginal list is:",mylist)


min_val=min(mylist)
print("minimum value is:",min_val)

max_val=max(mylist)
print("maximum value is:",max_val)


for x in range(1+n+1,1):
    newlist=((x-min_val)/(max_val-min_val))
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last part, you don't do anything with the elements of `mylist` at all.

You need something like

```
newlist = [(x - min_val)/(max_val - min_val) for x in mylist]
```

Using an explicit `for` loop, like you are trying to do:

```
newlist = []
for x in mylist: # sic!
    newlist.append((x - min_val) / (max_val - min_val))
```

Comment: @atmatm 1) The loop body wasn't ever executed, because the second argument to `range` is less than the first (`start` > `stop`); 2) inside the loop, `newlist` was (would be) assigned a floating point value. So in the end (if there was anything going on) you'd have a single number in `newlist`. 3) That number wouldn't have anything to do with the initial list, because `x` changes in a `range`, i.e. it's an integer, whereas it should acquire the values of elements of `mylist`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are re-assigning newlist every step of the for.

```
  for x in range(1+n+1,1):
      newlist.append((x-min_val)/(max_val-min_val))
  print(newlist)
```

Then, you most likely need to fix your 'range' function [If using python2];
And finally you probably need to make those int into floats to avoid integer division [If using python2]

```
  for x in mylist:
      newlist.append(float(x-min_val)/(max_val-min_val))
  print(newlist)
```

Comment: It's Python3, no need for conversion to `float`.

Comment: Ah @LevLevitsky, I hadn't noticed the Python3 tag and just thought he was trying to use the newer print(). To make this work in python2 it is required (and this code works in 2.7). I wouldn't be surprised if my 'range' argument also doesn't apply to Python3 (I never learned every difference but this one would be useful).